# How can I turn VSCode's sub word navigation off?

Tags: visual-studio-code, snakecasing

In a snake_cased language, I would want to navigate variablewise and not word_wise and also exclude sigils like @, % or / from these stops.

Example:

`|$here_she_goes_again; #the pipe marks my cursor position`

With one Ctrl+Right, I want to land on the space before the semicolon,

`$here_she_goes_again|; #the pipe marks my cursor position`

then, with a Ctrl+Left, I want to return to the beginning of the line.

`|$here_she_goes_again; #the pipe marks my cursor position`

Somebody got this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this into your `settings.json`:

```
"[javascript]": {
  "editor.wordSeparators": "`~!@#%^&*()-=+[{]}\|;:'",.<>/?"
}
```

Use whatever your language identifier is.  I deleted the `$` from the default separators to get your example to work for javascript.  You can remove the other characters you indicated.  The `underscore` was already not in the default for me.  Just make sure those characters are not in the language-specific setting shown above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the extension [Select By](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by#move-by) and the command `moveby.regex`

You are able to define a regex to search and bind this to `Ctrl+Left` and another to `Ctrl+Right`

In the key binding you can limit this to a particular languageID.